# rewirterule in apache conversion to nginx equivalent rewrite rule

Tags: rewrite, apache2

Apache server rewrite rule has been written below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/cesop(.*)$"  "http://LSVCHN-EPAP01/cesop$1"  [P]
```

In Internet browser, type below:
`https://server1.com/`
html page from server1 displayed.

There is href tag as below and once clicked then
`<a href="https://server1.com/cesop/homepage.php">CESOP Application</a>`
then it should get html details from `http://LSVCHN-EPAP01/cesop$1`

Nginx written like below but it is giving error:

> Error - This site can not be reached
> http://LSVCHN-EPAP01/cesop/homepage.php

But the same above link provides html details while doing
`curl -Lv http://LSVCHN-EPAP01/cesop/homepage.php`

Kindly let me know how can apache rewrite rule to be converted.

Comment: The Apache web server is contacted with the domain `server1.com`, the nginx with the hostname `LSVCHN-EPAP01`? If nginx brings an error, what does the nginx config look like? And what about Apache and nginx, what is in the log?

Comment: Here is the configuration in the rewrite rule:    location /cesop {   rewrite ^/cesop?$  http://LSVCHN-EPAP01/cesop$1;

   }  Log error says like below: 165.225.17.97 - - [28/Aug/2022:17:45:12 +0100] "GET /cesop/homepage.php HTTP/1.1" 302 145 "https://server1.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" \n\r Hope all required details and kindly let me know if any additioanl details are required.

Comment: Please add additional information to the question by editing it so that it can be properly formatted.